# Can't provide correct system library to Swift on Heroku

Tags: linux, swift, heroku, perfect

I am trying to deploy Swift on Heroku, I want to compile a project that uses Perect.

I specified [this build-pack](https://github.com/kylef/heroku-buildpack-swift) for Swift.

The first issue was this one:

> In file included from
>   /tmp/.../Packages/LinuxBridge-2.0.2/LinuxBridge/LinuxBridge.c:2:
>   /tmp/.../Packages/LinuxBridge-2.0.2/LinuxBridge/include/LinuxBridge.h:6:10:
>   fatal error: 'uuid/uuid.h' file not found
>   `#`include `<uuid/uuid.h>`

Apparently that's because this library isn't there by default, so to install it I added [another build pack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) that enables to install those using apt.

This build pack requires you to provide a `Aptfile` that contains the name of the required libraries, here is mine:

```
openssl
libssl-dev
uuid-dev
```

Unfortunately, when trying to build again there is still the same issue (it can't find uuid), and yet, it seems that the apt build pack was able to install what I wanted (from what I see in the logs).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly the same scenario (I am using Perfect-SMTP on Kitura), I was getting the same error complaining about uuid.h not being found. The following made it go away:

```
apt-get install uuid-dev
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Actually I was able to use another build pack that works but when I had tried apt-get it didn't worked either  Anyway now my problem is solved !  Thank you !

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Do you mind sharing how you solved the problem? Cheers!

Comment: @JohnDough I was using a "generic" build pack for Swift on Heroku, but then I tried the one made by Perfect (I think its this one https://github.com/theam/Perfect-Heroku-Buildpack.git) and it worked !